# How to I make a tkinter window transparent when I click away

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to make a tkinter window transparent when the mouse is not hovering on the window?

Comment: Yes there is a way. Bind a Leave event to the root and set the `wm_attributes('-alpha', value)`

Comment: it may not work on some systems. And it makes transparent all elements/widgets. It can't make transparent only main window and keep normal widgets inside this window.